# Local Github Compare View

Tags: git, diff

I am pretty new to github, and really appreciate its compare view: it shows the differences between diffenent versions, and allows users to comment on each change. I hope I can do the same thing locally, that is, to have the same effect without internet connection, or even without uploading my files to github.

Now, I understand that the command `git log` or `diff` can do similar jobs. However, in terms of clarity, it does not come close to what github compare view offers. For example, on github, not only the different lines will be selected, the words altered are highlighted; also, it seems to me that I cannot comment on each change/line/word. Perhaps I have to use more sophisticated options?

Answer (score 2):

#### GUI:

The [Atom Editor](https://atom.io) natively supports Git Diff, seamlessly integrating with Git, as well as provides numerous additional extensions for Git.

- Atom is a cross-platform editor - simply copy/paste your `.atom` directory to your user's home directory (`%UserProfile%\.atom` || `~/.atom`) to maintain your settings and installed extensions.
- There are also extensions for comparing two files that aren't apart of a repo, such as:

  - [compare-files](https://atom.io/packages/compare-files)
  - [split-diff](https://atom.io/packages/split-diff)

You may also find the following helpful:

- [How do I view 'git diff' output with my preferred diff tool/viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/255212/6819406)

---

#### CLI:

[Vim](https://www.vim.org) supports Diff viewing, and if utilizing Git regularly from a terminal, [Oh-My-ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/) can be utilized with ZSH (**Z**-**SH**ell) to make managing the repo easier via its Git plugin

- To enable the plugin, add the following to your `~/.zshrc` **`plugins`** section

  ```
  plugins=(
    ... colorize copydir git per-directory-history themes z zsh-syntax-highlighting
  )
  ```

  - **[colorize](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/colorize):** *Syntax highlights files*
  - **[copydir](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/copydir):** *Copies current directory path to clipboard*
  - **[git](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/git):** *Adds git functionality*
  - **[per-directory-history](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/per-directory-history):** *Quite helpful for Git repos*
  - **[themes](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/themes):** *Certain themes are more Git oriented*
  - **[z](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/z):** *A handy plugin for efficiency*
  - **[zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting):** *Syntax highlights commands*
- [Oh-My-ZSH cheatsheet](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Cheatsheet)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the topic of vim [1](https://vim.org)

Vim and git work very well together when setting `vimdiff` as the *difftool* for git.

for example:

```
 git difftool <commit> -- <file>
```

will open a vimdiff window consisting of a side-by-side view comparing your current version of `<file>` with (a temporary copy of) the version from `<commit>`.

You can then even use vim's diff features to selectively apply differences to each file as you like. [2]

(note: You won't be able to change what is stored in `<commit>` this way)

relevant configuration for git is:

```
$ git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
```

and optionally:

```
$ git config --global difftool.prompt false
```

Git is very well documented, on (at least) many systems `git help diff` will take you to the man page, alternatively `man git-diff` will likely do the same.

[2]: in vim, `:diffget` and `:diffput` will move differences over from/to the other pane. `:help diff` for more information.

Comment: It works for me! Still, I wonder if you copy and paste the commit hash every time, or there is a faster way to do it? Also, is it possible to use `git difftool ...` to compare two past commits?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can also compare past commits. 

git is very well documented, so `man git-diff` will likely contain the answer to if and how.

Answer (score 1):

You need [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) to view diff locally. As you are already familiar with git and github, this should be the most straight forward solution.